# How to open a shell script in a new Terminal window and run it with administrator privileges

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, sudo, administrator

I need to programmatically open a shell script in a Terminal window and run it with administrator privileges. I'm using osascript as it displays a convenient prompt for an admin login/password.

I'm currently using this :

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "open -a Terminal \"'"$appDir"'\"" with administrator privileges'
```

The trouble is, even after entering the credentials in the OS X prompt, the newly opened script will beg for a password at the first sudo command.

How do I pass the admin credentials to the opened script?

Comment: Can't you run the script requiring admin rights directly (instead of using Terminal as an in-between)?

Comment: No, because running the script directly executes it in the background. I need a Terminal window for user interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try writing a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/bin/id
```

save this as `something.command`, change its permissions to executable with `chmod +x`, and then run this from AppleScript with

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "open -a Terminal ./something.command"'
```

Instead of `/usr/bin/id` you can call whatever script you need to run with admin privileges then.

EDIT:

This will work:

```
osascript -e 'do shell script "sudo /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal" with administrator privileges'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is similar to the current state: something.command prompts for a password, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I would like to have an OS X prompt window, which allows entering another user with admin privileges for example. Osascript offers such a functionality with 'with administrator privileges'.

Comment: Last edit contains the solution

Comment: Thank you Brethil, your edit did the trick. I ended up using this line: `osascript -e 'do shell script "sudo /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal \"'"$appDir"'\"" with administrator privileges'`. Admin privileges asked by the OS X dialog were successfully passed to the executed script.